# Is there a jQuery equivalent of this flash effect? (sliding effect)

Tags: jquery, slider

I know Coda Slider and Easy Slider. But, I would like a jQuery plugin which shows the next and previous image with low opacity. Like this example: http://www.muratsuyur.com/. Should I just modify Coda Slider or Easy Slider to obtain that result? Or there's a plugin which has the whole effect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes jquery supports `opacity` like that. **[See jquery effects here.](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can do all of that with jquery. all your elements should be position: absolute and then by using the animate function targeting the height and left and top property you can re create these effects. note that to get the sequencing right you need to have some of your animate as a callback function of the previous one to get this right.